# Websphere App Server 6.1: Redeploy after web.xml change required?

Tags: websphere, web.xml, websphere-6.1

In WebSphere Application Server 6.1, is it necessary to redeploy the application (WAR/EAR) every time a change is made to a web.xml descriptor file?

Comment: Yes, it is.  You have to edit the web.xml, repackage the WAR, and redeploy.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to confirm that..

Comment: @duffymo - Should have been an answer (thus moving this off of the unanswered questions list)

Comment: @Tim Post - Should I move it?  It didn't seem like much of an answer at the time.

Comment: @duffymo Yes please. This is still "Unanswered"...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you refer to by "a change is made to a `web.xml` descriptor file".

If you made a change to the `web.xml` file inside your IDE, then obviously this change has to somehow make it to the application server's world. Repackage your WAR file and deploy to WebSphere, for changes to take effect.

If you made a change to the `web.xml` file inside WebSphere's internal directories (the `installedApps` directory somewhere underneath the profile) - a practice I'd advise against - then a server restart would be sufficient for the changes to take effect. It goes without saying though, that your changes will disappear next time the application is deployed.